# Is it possible to load a CSV file with Pandoc and producing markdown file for each line?

Tags: pandoc

I have a CSV file similar to below:

```
0,Bob's Business,50 some address,zip,telephone
1,Jill's Business,25 some address,zip,telephone
...
```

I would like to take this CSV file and have Pandoc produce a markdown file for each line in the CSV file. Each column accessible from a variable to be used in a markdown template file.

Is it possible to load a CSV file and produce markdown/html files in this way?

Answer (score 2):

I can see three ways.

#### Use a static site generator

I would probably just use a tool like [jekyll with its data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/).

#### Alternative 1: Convert to YAML and use pandoc's template engine

1. Put something like this in `mytemplate.md`:

   ```
   $for(data)$
   $data$
   $endfor$
   ```
2. Convert the csv to a JSON or YAML file
3. load that file with the [`--metadata-file` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata-file) and use the template to render the output:

   ```
   echo '' | pandoc --metadata-file data.yaml -t markdown --template mytemplate.md -o output.md
   ```

#### Alternative 2: Write a pandoc filter

There are many pandoc filters (like [pandoc-placetable](https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable) or [pantable](https://ickc.github.io/pantable/)) that read csv and convert it to a pandoc table. But you want to convert it to a pandoc metadata format (which is usually parsed from the YAML frontmatter of markdown files). I guess you could adjust one of those pandoc filters to your purposes.

Comment: I'm actually using Hugo which is a static site generator, but it doesn't support the same features as Jekyll (I wish it did). I'm basically trying to do what Jekyll does to produce the markdown files for Hugo. I will give this a try.

Comment: Are you sure Hugo doesn't support it? What about https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/#data-driven-content

Comment: Data templates do not produce pages, they allow you to load data from JSON etc. to display on pages. But they don't actually produce a page themselves.